# Kubuntu 16.10 doesn't let user login automatically

Tags: kubuntu, login, password, encryption, lvm

I recently installed Kubuntu 16.10 and decided to use Full Disk Encryption during installation (LVM with Encryption was the option I chose I believe).

Now the thing is that the system asks me for the encryption password when I boot it up *and* the user password to login. I'd rather just have the system login automatically once the encryption password has been entered since I'm the only user on the system (i.e. 1 password is sufficient for me).

So I looked through the system settings and found "Account Details" which has "User Manager" as an option (so `System Settings -> Account Details -> User Manager`). Under here, my user has the the check box "Automatic Login". I toggle that, click Apply. Restart the computer to test and I still get two password prompts. If I go back into the settings after the reboot, I see the Automatic Login is unchecked. How do I get Kubuntu 16.10 to let me login automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be a *bug* as reported [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-armadaxp/+bug/1565601). The fix they offered is as follows:

1. Create a file `/etc/sddm.conf`
2. Add the following:

   ```
   [Autologin]
   User=YourLogonID
   Session=plasma.desktop
   ```

   - Please note `YourLogonID` == `YourLogonName`
3. Then try again.

Source:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-armadaxp/+bug/1565601